# Riemann Sum Coding

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I am just testing my hands in Python with the midpoint Riemann sum but I seem to be missing a step as my answer was wrong. Here is a sample of my code:

```
from math import pi, sin
a=0
b=pi/2
n=10

dx=(b-a)/n
ends = [a+i*dx for i in range(n+1)]
mids=[(i+i-1)/2 for i in ends]
f = lambda x: x*sin(x)
area = [f(i)*dx for i in mids]
sum(area)
```

My answer should be *1* but I got *0.5022*. I suspect my comprehension list under **mids** is wrong but can't figure out how to fix it. Any help will be well appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the gentleman's name was [Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann).

Comment: hahaha... Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

`mids` should be

```
mids = [(ends[i] + ends[i-1]) / 2 for i in range(1, len(ends))]
```

`i-1` is not the `i-1`th element of `ends`. It is just the `i`th element minus 1.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're taking 11 segments, not 10, because of `range(n+1)`

Then your calculation is wrong.

```
ends[0] == 0 (a == 0, i == 0  => a+i*dx == 0)
=> mids[0] == -1/2 (i == ends[0] => (i+i-1)/2 == -1/2)
```

If you use `range(1, n+1)` instead, you get:

```
ends[0] == pi/20 (a == 0, i == 1 => a+i*dx == pi/20)
=> mids[0] == pi/20-1/2 (i == ends[0] == pi/20 => (i+i-1)/2 == (pi/10-1)/2)
```

These are still incorrect - `ends` looks OK, but `mids[0]` needs to evaluate to `pi/40`

My suggestion is to use a debugger to check the values at each point here and confirm they are what you think they should be.